# is it possible to type the projected content a component can take in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Just like we can limit the components or tags the children prop of a component can have in react. I have been wondering if we can do the same in angular?

I looked around and the closest I found was that you can type NgTemplateOutlet, but I was not looking for templates but for typing directly projected content. Which for that the closest thing is to make sure you select only the elements you want with the "select" attribute. But that does not enforce how many or which components/elements you can put in the content.